# I need to leave the gnome desktop - but it seems all attempts are blocked

Tags: gnome, crash

I am getting regular crashes of gnome desktop.(which entails reboot every time)
Also i simply don't like the gnome desktop especially for package management. I want the old system.
I have attempted to load 3 other desktops and succeeded with none.
I now desperately need help or i have to leave ubuntu after many years.
One update even tries to access libreoffice (which i have deleted - i use the still better openoffice)  What's that got to do with a screen update? and apparently fail the process because of it.
I have followed the instructions and they all fail.

HELP......

Comment: $ sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop fails  every ti9me with:tasksel: apt-get failed (100).  No explanation available.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop` to get [Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/).

Comment: GNOME Shell crashes are usually the result of a bad extension. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable all extensions, and see it improves. Report back to @heynnema